# Loading new images via AJAX don't get same jQuery properies

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, infinite-scroll

I have a web page that loads pictures in a infinity scroll typ of way. Also I have a javascript that put a animation on the picture. The problem I'm facing is that the new images that are loaded will not get the animation properties.

First I have my Javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(
    function() {
        jQuery('.scroll_container').scrollExtend(
            {   
                'target': 'div#scroll_items',           
                'url': '/popular_data.php',
                'newElementClass' : 'mosaic-block cover2',
                'onSuccess' : ''
            }
        );
    }
);



        jQuery(function($){

            $('.cover2').mosaic({
                animation   :   'slide',    //fade or slide
                anchor_y    :   'top',      //Vertical anchor position
                hover_y     :   '40px'      //Vertical position on hover
            });


        });

    </script>
```

What I would like to do is that the variable OnSuccess should call the cover2 mosaic function. But my Javascript knowledge is not that good. But i think this would solve the problem.

The plugins I'm using is: 
http://buildinternet.com/project/mosaic/ and 
http://contextllc.com/tools/jQuery-infinite-scroll-live-scroll

I have notice that if I append the javascript to the popular_data.php file then it will work on the second to last picture but never the last loaded picture.